# Is concave image of a compact convex set bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, fixed-point-theorems

**Definition [Concave]**: In a topological vector space $(V, \tau)$ ($\tau$ is neither discrete nor indiscrete), let $C$ be a convex subset and $f$ a real-valued function defined on $C$. $f$ is concave iff
$$f(\lambda\,x_1 + (1 - \lambda)\,x_2) \geq \lambda\,f(x_1) + (1 - \lambda)\,f(x_2)\hspace{0.2in}\forall\,x_1, x_2\in C\hspace{0.1in}\text{and}\hspace{0.1in}\forall\,\lambda\in[0, 1]$$

This question is inspired by the proof of **Theorem 1.24** included in this [note](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~prazak/vyuka/101/Literatura/vittorino-FP.pdf). The proof assumed that in a locally convex topological vector space $(X, \tau)$, if $f$ is concave, then when $K$ is compact convex, $f(K)$ is bounded.

I would like to see a counter example if this is false but when I am trying to prove it correct, I can not proceed at some place and below is my attempt:

**Proof.** Assume by contradiction, there exists $x \in K$ such that $\sup_{y \in K}\,f(y) = \infty$. Then find $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(y_m) > M$.
Pick $\lambda \in (0, 1)$, by concavity, we have:

$$f[\lambda\,x + (1 - \lambda)\,y_m] \geq \lambda\,f(x) + (1 - \lambda)\,f(y_m)$$

$$f[(1 - \lambda)\,x + \lambda\,y_m] \geq (1 - \lambda)\,f(x) + \lambda\,f(y_m)$$

Combine these two inequalities and then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
    & \lambda\,f[\lambda\,x + (1 - \lambda)\,y_m] + (1 - \lambda)\,f[(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda\,y_m]\\
    &\geq \lambda^2\,f(x) + \lambda\,(1 - \lambda)f(y_m) + (1 - \lambda)^2\,f(x) + \lambda\,(1 - \lambda)f(y_m)\\
    &> \lambda^2\,f(x) + (1 - \lambda)^2\,f(x) + 2\,\lambda\,(1 - \lambda)\,M
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
$$

Meanwhile, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
    &\lambda\,f[\lambda\,x + (1 - \lambda)\,y_m] + (1 - \lambda)\,f[(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda\,y_m]\\
    &\leq f[\lambda^2\,x + (1 - \lambda)^2\,x + 2\,\lambda\,(1 - \lambda)y_m]\\
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
    &\lambda^2\,f(x) + (1 - \lambda)^2\,f(x) + 2\,\lambda\,(1 - \lambda)\,M\\
    & < f[\lambda^2\,x + (1 - \lambda)^2\,x + 2\,\lambda\,(1 - \lambda)\,y_m]\\
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now let $\lambda = \frac{1}{n}\,(n \in \mathbb{N})$, then:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
    &\frac{1}{n^2}\,f(x) + (1 - \frac{1}{n})^2\,f(x) + 2\,(1 - \frac{1}{n})\,\frac{M}{n}\\
    & < f[\frac{1}{n^2}\,x + (1 - \frac{1}{n})^2\,x + 2\,(1 - \frac{1}{n})\,\frac{1}{n}\,y_m]\\
    &\text{and we can see this holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$}\\
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then I can not proceed because there is no guarantee the right hand side of the inequality will converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: What you have called concave is usually called convex

Comment: That is actually a typo ... Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take a vector space $X\ne\{0\}$ supplied with the indiscrete topology $\mathcal T = \{\emptyset, X\}$. Let $f\ne 0$ be a linear functional on $X$. Then $X$ is compact and convex, but $f(X) = \mathbb R$.

If you are willing to assume that the space is Hausdorff and $f$ is upper semicontinous (i.e. $\{x:\ f(x)\ge c\}$ are closed for all $c$) then the claim is true. However, is has nothing to do with concavity/convexity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is the same answer I heard from my teacher but (just try to be a bit more greedy) I wish to know whether or not a concave function defined on a non-trivial compact set has the mentioned property. In the original proof (you can refer to the link), what is defined is that $\Phi: K \times K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \Phi(\cdot, y)$ lower semi-continuous for all $y \in K$ and $\Phi(x, \cdot)$ concave for all $x \in K$

Comment: I do not see the relation of your question to that paper. In my counterexample, every subset of $X$ is compact, and $X$ can be large. So what is a nontrivial compact set?

Comment: In the note, in the proof of Theorem 1.24, the author assumes $\sup_{y \in K}\,\Phi(x, y) < \infty\hspace{0.1in}\,\forall\,y \in K$ (this is stated in the first few lines). This is why I asked this question because I am not sure if it is true given that $\Phi(x, \cdot)$ is concave. I should correct my previous comment because "trivial compact set" is not rigorous. I should say I prefer to see an counter-example where the topology is not discrete or indiscrete.

Comment: Another reason is because of the application of Theorem 1.24, which is in Theorem 2.23. When the topology is indiscrete, only a constant function can be continuous and I believe this might not fit in the setting when Theorem 2.23 will be used (according to Theorem 2.23, I mean in general a lost function will not be constant in a game).